# Highscore variable not working on game

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I am currently developing a game using Phaser, and trying to implement a system to save the highscore from the current score. It isn't working for some reason and I don't know why, it seems to not be changing the highscore variable based on the current score.
I have put the simple game on Jsfiddle with the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/zpy8wLqf/
This is what I tried for the highscore variable.

```
highscore=0;
var currentscore;
if(this.currentscore>highscore){
    highscore =this.currentscore;
}
```

The textures are not there, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Your code performs the check once, before the game has even started. You need to do this check whenever the player dies or when the score changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thats because your check only runs on state start, try putting the check inside the reset

```
reset: function() {
    if(this.currentscore>highscore){
    highscore =this.currentscore;
    }
    // Start the 'main' state, which restarts the game
    begin.state.start('adventure');
}
```